# Open Word doc in Powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Trying to open a doc file with the help of below script in vba

```
Sub FTP()

Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptApp.Visible = True
pptApp.WindowState = 2
Set ppt = pptApp.Presentations.Open("C:\Genie-Tools 2.0\FTP-Request new-Fom.docx")

End Sub
```

But it's not opening as i wanted, can anyone please help me with these

Comment: Can you do this using the PowerPoint application? No, you get an error message. That's not a format it can open.

Comment: The word file is opening in powerpoint application only

Comment: Hi John, Can you please help if any other script that can help me to open word file in powerpoint macros

Comment: Using VBA, you can create a PowerPoint macro that will open the file in Word and copy and paste the content to PowerPoint. Or you can open it in Word and access the Send to Microsoft PowerPoint command, which will export it to that format. Here are manual methods that can be automated: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-a-word-document-c926adb3-4aa9-4b13-a5d1-587c6752bda7